# Rhino 1.7 in shell doesn't map the arrow keys for history

Tags: javascript, shell, mozilla, rhino, key-bindings

I downloaded Mozilla Rhino so I can use the interactive JavaScript console through

```
java -jar js.jar
```

I can get into the prompt, and everything is all working fine. Except... My arrow keys are not mapped to move the cursor back and forth or to use the history function with up and down. Now, according to the documentation, these features do exist in the interactive console, but they seem to break on Mac OS. I need some pointers to change these settings or add code to support this?

When using JSC, I do not have this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in key bindings when running just "js.jar" like that. What you may want to do is look into the [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) "console runner" project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is an interactive interpreter and Rhino does support history and such. I am using the Mozilla Rhino interpreter to verify the code as it used by another application - so without the keybindings I don't need it to be interactive at all. I am a lousy programmer :) Thanks for the JLine link.

Comment: Well, Rhino does not display any key bindings at all when I run it as you suggest under Linux. In other words, launching "js.jar" as you did, I can type in JavaScript statements and they work, but there are no key bindings to go to previous commands in the history. Hitting arrow keys just causes the escape sequences to be echoed back out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with version 1.7R2 they added support for JLine. You just need to add it to the class path e.g.

> java -cp js.jar:lib/jline-0.9.93.jar
>   org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/New_in_Rhino_1.7R2